# building GEOS from source and pointing to the right Python version

Tags: python, linux, build, geos

I'm trying to install GEOS from source and configure it with the right Python bindings (as shown here http://scigeo.org/articles/howto-install-latest-geospatial-software-on-linux.html#geos). The Linux distro where I'm installing it comes with Python 2.6 so when doing:

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/source/geos-3.3.8/build --enable-python
```

It points to the wrong version of Python (as expected)

```
checking for python... /usr/bin/python
checking for python version... 2.6
checking for python platform... linux2
checking for python script directory... ${prefix}/lib/python2.6/site-packages
checking for python extension module directory... ${exec_prefix}/lib64/python2.6/site-packages
```

I've tried to point it to the right direction by doing something like:

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/python/geos-3.3.8/build --enable-python=/opt/python/Python-3.4.3/python
```

but no luck:

```
configure: error: bad value /opt/python/Python-3.4.3/python for --enable-python
```

Is there anyway (without messing around with /usr/bin/python that I can get GEOS build pointing to the right Python version?)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the linked article and the [README for GEOS](https://trac.osgeo.org/geos/browser/trunk/README#L92), Python bindings were dropped for version 3.0, which was released in 2006.

If you need to use GEOS for Python, use [Shapely](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely).

Comment: Shapely seems to require GEOS (GEOS >=3.3 (Shapely 1.2.x requires only GEOS 3.1 but YMMV))...

Comment: Yes, Shapely is a Python library based on GEOS.